# Bootstrap 4 make entire li area clickable in drop-down menu

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Working on a multi-level bootstrap 4 menu button and trying to solve a problem with the selectable area.

For the purpose of illustrating the issues I have put borders on the current clickable area (**black**) and I've highlighted in (**red**) the area i'm trying to fill as clickable.

Here is my fiddle: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zWeqbE

## Initial dropdown menu

I would like to have the entire `<li>` are highlighted and clickable - right now there is a top margin and bottom margin which i can't seem to get rid off.

[image]

## Submenu

The `<a>` links are clickable but the clickable area is limited to the link itself whereas i want the clickable area to fill the entire `<li>`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to have the entire `<li>` are highlighted and clickable -
>   right now there is a top margin and bottom margin which i can't seem
>   to get rid off.

Problem is parent `ul` has a padding and each `.dropdown-divider` has a padding, It can be fix by moving the divider's padding to each `<li>`

> The `<a>` links are clickable but the clickable area is limited to the link
>   itself whereas i want the clickable area to fill the entire `<li>`

Fix is to move the `dropdown menulink` class to `<a>` instead of it's parent `<li>`

Sample code pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zWeByy